# The user tags on elections.stackexchange are not being encoded

Tags: bug, status-completed, election-page

If I click on a C# tag for any of the candidates the link is something like

```
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:16587+[c#]
```

With the `#` not being encoded. So for George Stocker I'd only see some of the results.

[image: George Stocker]

If the tag were encoded to `[c%23]` like it is everywhere else, I should have gotten 164 results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whoops, that's no good. It's been [fixed in source](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-election-stats/source/detail?r=93aa60762678bcc5f1f1220d997c241c90f9dc3c), and will be resolved on the site following the next redeployment.

Comment: This has been deployed (: